# Let $G$ be a finite group of even order. Prove that there exists $a \in G$ of order $2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group of even order. Prove that there exists an element $a \in G$ of order $2$.

My attempt:

Since the order of $a$ is even, $o(a)$ = the least positive integer $n$ such that $a^{2n}$=e.

Let $o(a)= 2n$

$a^{2n} = (a^2)^n = a^n = e$

Comment: Nope. $o(a)$ is the least positive intger $n$ such that $a^n=e$. The order of $a$ need not be even a priori

Answer (score 1):

The map $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is an involutionary map of $G$ to itself, hence must have an even number of fixpoints. As $e$ is one fixpoint, ther must exist at least one more fixpoint $a$. Then $a=a^{-1}$ and $a\ne e$, so $o(a)=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a \in G$. Then $o(a) = 2k$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $a^k \in G$ and $(a^k)^2 = e_G$. Since $a_k \neq e_G$, we conclude that $o(a_k) = 2$, therefore finishing the proof.